# Cross domain post, Request NULL

Tags: c#, post, dns

Trying to post values below to another page.

This page http://from.com/Default.aspx

```
<input type="text" name="eml" id="eml" value="username"/>
<input type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="password"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="http://to.com/Default.aspx" />
```

In debugging mode my breakpoints got hit, and values of eml & pwd is null. What am i doing wrong? If i use WebRequest i can get the values. But this version not working. Can anybody help me please.

This page http://to.com/Default.aspx.cs

```
var username = Request.Form["eml"]; 
var password = Request.Form["pwd"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add runat server to both input fields. like this:

```
<input runat="server" type="text" name="eml" id="eml" value="username"/>
<input runat="server" type="text" name="pwd" id="pwd" value="password"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" PostBackUrl="http://to.com/Default.aspx" />
```

Then in your post back method you can access the controls like this:

```
var eml = eml.Value;
var pwd = pwd.Value;
```

Comment: They are not in the same application. Different applications and domains.

Comment: In that case you will need to use HttpWebRequest in to.com/Default.aspx.cs I don't think it's possible the way you are trying to do it currently.